# SQL Server : Map Row To LIKE Input

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to understand which exact `LIKE` condition pulls each row in my queries. I have a for instance of what I would like to see below, but I am not sure if it is possible.

```
SELECT NAME, CITY 
FROM Customers
WHERE NAME LIKE '%ABC%' OR
      NAME LIKE '%DEF%' OR
      NAME LIKE '%GHI%'
```

Output:

```
NAME            CITY       LIKE
----------------------------------
ABC Corp        Dallas     '%ABC%'
DEF Inc.        Chicago    '%DEF%'
GHI Industries  New York   '%GHI%'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put the condition in the `select`:

```
SELECT NAME, CITY,
       (CASE WHEN NAME LIKE '%ABC%' THEN 'ABC'
             WHEN NAME LIKE '%DEF%' THEN 'DEF'
             WHEN NAME LIKE '%GHI%' THEN 'GHI'
        END) as which 
FROM Customers
WHERE NAME LIKE '%ABC%' OR
      NAME LIKE '%DEF%' OR
      NAME LIKE '%GHI%';
```

I slight variant will let you bring together multiple conditions:

```
SELECT NAME, CITY,
       CONCAT_WS(',',
                 (CASE WHEN NAME LIKE '%ABC%' THEN 'ABC' END)
                 (CASE WHEN NAME LIKE '%DEF%' THEN 'DEF' END)
                 (CASE WHEN NAME LIKE '%GHI%' THEN 'GHI')
                ) as which 
FROM Customers
WHERE NAME LIKE '%ABC%' OR
      NAME LIKE '%DEF%' OR
      NAME LIKE '%GHI%';
```

You can also simplify the `WHERE` to:

```
WHERE NAME regexp 'ABC|DEF|GHI'
```

Comment: thank you. this was very easy to implement. appreciate your time!

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT NAME, CITY, '%ABC%' as [like]
FROM Customers
WHERE NAME LIKE '%ABC%' 

union all

SELECT NAME, CITY, '%DEF%' 
FROM Customers
WHERE NAME LIKE '%DEF%' 

union all

SELECT NAME, CITY, '%GHI%' 
FROM Customers
WHERE NAME LIKE '%GHI%'
```

Comment: this is great, thank you. but lets say I have a list of 1,000 inputs ... Is there a way I can do this at scale? Writing 1,000 different SELECT statements would take a really long time

Comment: You have 1000 `where` conditions?

Comment: its hypothetical - for instance, lets say I am trying to cross reference a list of potential customers to customers already in our database. I could easily get a list of 1000+ potential customers that I have to cross reference

Comment: Then you would not use `like` since you have the exact text and do not use text search. Then use `in` or join against a table containing the customers

Comment: when i am given a prospective name it RARELY is spelled the same way in our database. hence why i use LIKE instead of IN

Answer (score 1):

```
select *
from (select name
            ,city
            ,case when name like '%ABC%' then '%ABC%'
                  when name like '%DEF%' then '%DEF%'
                  when name like '%GHI%' then '%GHI%'
             end as [like]
      from customers
     )
where [like] is not null
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put your LIKE-values in a table as well, as many as you want, and then join the two tables like this:

```
DECLARE @Customers TABLE (NAME VARCHAR(20), CITY VARCHAR(20))
INSERT INTO @Customers VALUES ('ABC Corp','Dallas'), ('DEF Inc.','Chicago'), ('GHI Industries','New York'), ('No Match','No Match')

DECLARE @LIKE_VALUES TABLE (LIKE_VALUE VARCHAR(20))
INSERT INTO @LIKE_VALUES VALUES ('%ABC%'), ('%DEF%'), ('%GHI%')

SELECT C.NAME, C.CITY, L.LIKE_VALUE
FROM @Customers C
JOIN @LIKE_VALUES L ON C.NAME LIKE L.LIKE_VALUE
```

Output:

```
NAME            CITY        LIKE_VALUE
--------------- ----------- ----------
ABC Corp        Dallas      %ABC%
DEF Inc.        Chicago     %DEF%
GHI Industries  New York    %GHI%
```